# Remove any leading spaces (not including tabs)

Tags: vim, whitespace

I'm trying to remove leading spaces in vim but not touch tabs.  For instance, if each of the lines below have a leading tab, but `b_line` has an additional two spaces, how can I just remove those two spaces?

```
a_line
  b_line
c_line
```

I'm using this to remove all unwanted trailing whitespace:

```
:%s/\s\+$//
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
:%s/^\(\t\+\)\s\+/\1/
```

It preserves the leading tab characters, but removes spaces, following those tabs.